# Why is .scrollTop(); not working well?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a sample alert if you scroll after a certain height, but the code does not work. Have a look:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
     var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
     if (scrolled = 18) {
        alert("ciao");
     }
});
```

The Google Chrome's console does not report me any bugs and jQuery is linked properly. Do you know which is the problem?

Comment: The problem is `if (scrolled === 18)`

Comment: Is `scrolled = 18` a typo?

Comment: You are setting 18 to `scrolled`: `if (scrolled = 18)` single `=` is an assignement

Answer (score 3):

Your assignment operator `=` should be a comparison operator `==`.

```
if (scrolled == 18) {// ==
               alert("ciao");
}
```

Update:

Don't know why you want `alert()` at exactly `18`. But you should better use this:

```
if (scrolled >= 18) {// ==
               alert("ciao");
}
```

Comment: Beware, `$(window).scrollTop()` could possibly never returns exactly 18, i guess this would be better: `if (scrolled >= 18)`  e.g, this isn't working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/1bt79LL9/

Comment: Probably better to remove the `});` to avoid confusion or add the starting brackets

Comment: @Huangism. My bad, removed.

Comment: @A.Wolff. I guess you are right. But `==` shud also work. http://jsfiddle.net/jc0hw6cy/1/

Comment: @Zee It could or not. For me, when scrolling in your jsFiddle, `$(window).scrollTop()` is never equals to `18`: `10 - 20 - 30 - 40 - etc...`

Comment: @A.Wolff. Your fiddle works for me. don't know why its happening then :)

Comment: @Zee It depends how you scroll the body, using mousewheel or scroll bar or keyboard. It depends of device too, etc...

Comment: @A.Wolff. Updated code. you can edit the answer to add any extra info.

Comment: That was exactly that I was trying to do. I want to fix an element after a certain height with >= but it does not work as well, so I tried with == and then, for despair, I tried also = but I know it's an assignment operator! The alert is to debug my code.

Comment: @DavideScanu. Can you create a fiddle showing your problem?

Comment: Are you sure? For me it makes an alert every times I scroll the page

Comment: @DavideScanu Thats the way `if (scrolled >= 18) {` shud work. You shud get an alert after you cross `18` and for every value above 18, thats why once you cross 18 you keep on getting alerts, since the `event listener` is invoked whenever you are scrolling. To understand it better, give a larger value like 100 or so, and replace your `alert` with a `console.log`.